# Understanding as a mental simulation of reality

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling, visualization, spatial-cognition

This is a follow up to an [earlier question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/30271/34318). It appears that there is very little research of this phenomenon, our capacity to piece together and visualize a mental simulation of things we are trying to understand. This higher-level capacity stems from our basic ability create mental imagery, visual imagery in particular -- and there is plenty of research of that basic ability. However, creating the actual simulation also involves other mental skills, skills like:

1. The ability to connect the dots, to assemble, like a puzzle, larger models from smaller parts.
2. The ability to run this simulation by visualising how the smaller models interact and work together as parts of a virtual machine (of a virtual reality).

These additional skills allows us to create, in our minds, an interactive simulation of the world (rather than visualise static images), and use that simulation to achieve insights into how the reality operates under the hood,<sup>1</sup> and to predict real-life outcomes.

This capacity would explain the success of Carl Rogers' person-centered approach (a person have to piece together their own understanding by themselves, no one can do it for them). It also explains Lev Vygotsky's zone of proximal development -- a person can only add the pieces of the puzzle, so to speak, that are adjacent to the already completed parts.

Given the above, I wonder why there is so little research into this capacity? Is it because it is difficult to master and, therefore, quite rare?<sup>2</sup> Or because those of us who did master this skill lack the necessary introspection?

After all, only if we ourselves are conscious of this experience -- of how we understand things -- we would discover better ways of helping others, especially the children, to discover the same ability in them.

UPDATE: Even though this model of understanding cannot be confirmed by direct observations, it can still make testable predictions.<sup>3</sup> For example, we can start encouraging students to visualize, in their minds, the problems they are being asked solve, as well as the material they are trying to understand -- and then see if that improves their academic performance.

<sup>1</sup> For example, the discovery of the universal gravity by Isaac Newton.

<sup>2</sup> Which would explain why the capacity to understand varies widely -- in classrooms, etc.

<sup>3</sup> One can even argue that a theory can only be useful if it is testable -- if it can point out the actions that would lead to favorable outcomes. However, even this was not always the case. For example, the heliocentric cosmology didn't immediately lead to any [testable predictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair). However, it was an important piece of the puzzle and, as such, instrumental in discovery of the Newton's laws of motions as well as the universal gravity. Ironically, it took a whole century after Newton's discovery to [observe and measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment) the gravitational force directly (and only in 19th century we discovered a way to [confirm the Earth rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) -- by that time even Catholic church accepted it as a fact). None of this might be relevant to psychology *per se*, but it is important to know when we try to understand what science is about.

Comment: Observation is quite limited as a tool in science compared to experimentation. The phenomenon you're describing are not very accessible experimentally, so there are limits on what can be studied. There is a *lot* of study "around the edges", though, I mean basically the entire field of cognitive neuroscience would be just one of those edges. You also have people approaching it from more of a philosophical view, people trying to come bottom-up with mathematical formulations, but ultimately many of the hypotheses made can only be tested very indirectly.

Comment: I think in general it's a mistake to think that something we're "conscious of" gives us all that much insight into how it actually works; if you sit in a chair you probably think you're more or less sitting still but you're actually rotating quite rapidly around a massive object that is hurtling through space at unimaginable speeds in another reasonable reference frame.

Comment: @BryanKrause -- I wholeheartedly agree, this theory can only be tested indirectly (and  that's why I mentioned some of the indirect evidence). Even so, there might be a way to test it -- for example, by finding new methods to encourage and develop this capacity in children and to see if this would improve their academic performance.

Comment: There is also a lot of research into education at all ages with various motivating models, ranging from the practical to the theoretical; you'd have to first figure out what the new method is that would be motivated by whatever you're proposing and how that's different from what has already been tried whatever the motivation. Similarly in medicine, comprehensive models have not been that successful in leading to actual treatments; usually we work the opposite direction, we have something that we know works and spend our time trying to figure out why.